# Calling Python script /C++exe from PHP script

Tags: php, python

I am trying to execute my python script from php as below

```
 exec('python C:/wamp/www/Proj/bin/test_wrapper.py');
```

it didnt launch the test_wrapper.py
then i tried to create an exe using C++ instead of test_wrapper.py and tried to call that C++ exe from my php as below

```
 exec('C:/wamp/www/Proj/bin/LaunchEngine.exe');
```

It didnt work again.I am sure i am missing some very basic thing while using exec().I am a beginner for python and php. 
My php, python/C++ exe are in the same subdirectory(bin).
please help me.
For reference , here is my python script test_wrapper.py
    import subprocess

```
def main():
    script=subprocess.Popen('python proj2xml.py')
    script.wait()
    script=subprocess.Popen('python cost2xml.py')
    script.wait()

    launch_fcs_engine=subprocess.Popen('fcs.exe')
    launch_fcs_engine.wait()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked your server logs if they contain some error messages? Also, `exec` in php returns a string with the output of the called program. If you don't print that, you won't see anything.

Comment: What `exec` function returns?

Comment: My exec function doesnt return anything..I am supposed to launch an engine that has set of programs that writes output to specified folders. I am just expecting to launch the python script on clicking the submit button.rightnow, i have php script which changes the url location after hitting submit.so, i want to include the exec() function that launches the engine .. I dont know if i am using the right function to launch my engine. Please help.

Comment: Have you tried to execute any other thing with that function?
Also, to check what it returns use `print_r(exec("command"))`

Comment: Did you try system() function? http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 possibilities that I can think of.
1. You do not have a permission to execute the test_wrapper.py script, change the permission of the file,
2. If you are trying to run your PHP script through the browser, then the your PHP script execute on apache user, and your python do not have a permission to run as an apache ueser.
(When you test the python script on the command line, you're running as root. Chances are you're not running the webserver as root (which is a good thing), and the webserver's user does not have appropriate permissions to create and/or write to that file.)
I am not much familiar with the windows, please try chmod and chown linux command equivalent in windows.

Please verify.

Comment: I was able to get the python scripts execute by calling them seperately as below:          exec('C:/wamp/www/Proj/bin/cost2xml.py');  etc etc..But I am not able to execute the executable if i do this  exec('C:/wamp/www/Proj/bin/fcs.exe');

Comment: Also , I added header("Location:new.html") at the end of my php script..its working if i dont call the exe.I am curious to know about calling exe application from php and also changing the location..if my exe takes too long to run,,,how do i change the location and make the exe run in the background?please help

Comment: To execute the command in background try this, pclose(popen("start /B C:/wamp/www/Proj/bin/LaunchEngine.exe" , "r")); (This is for windows)

Can you try this and let me know ? Here is a link for your reference, http://zeroflag.wordpress.com/2007/05/12/start-command/

Comment: Do i have to use exit() after the pclose(popen(...)); yesterday, i used exec and it left the processes running overnight and thats using up all the CPU. when i used exec() it was running in the background,, and nothing showed up in the task manager.please let me know, if i have to use exit()?i will try pclose(popen()) also..thanks for looking into the issue.